# Selenium - Detect if external javascript file was loaded by browser - ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to integrate Selenium into my rails app for testing purposes, and surprisingly I'm having trouble with something I thought would be straight-forward: detecting if the browser is loading a certain external JavaScript file (or any external file) or not loading it.

I've come close to finding an answer with the "find_element" method but it seems that you can only search by :name, :id, :class or things like that and it's not quite what I want.

Has anyone solved this problem before?  Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well in chrome I can use the web inspector and the 'Network' tab to see that it is indeed being loaded.  I'd like a way for Selenium to pick up on that in a test.

Comment: In my opinion, this is more about how to detect it using Ruby/JavaScript, rather than Selenium. It's not about testing UI and interacting with DOM.

Comment: Agreed with the above, the UI is what Selenium deals with. This is **not** UI testing. This why "something this straight forward" is not possible with Selenium, or at least, not *easily* possible.